# Car won't start without disconnecting both battery posts

Tags: electrical, battery, starting, mercedes-benz

I have a 2001 Mercedes E430. I'm having problems getting it to start. Usually, I have to get a boost to get it to start. But I just discovered that disconnecting the battery completely gets it to start as well. After disconnecting the battery it will run fine for a few days. Also, I hear a single click sometimes when it doesn't start.

Also, may be related, my windows usually have problems going up. They will go up a little then stop. And I have to repeatedly push the up button. I noticed after disconnecting the battery this time, I did not have that problem.

Comment: It sounds as if you have a connection problem at the battery, where you get it to reconnect after you take the leads off the posts. Try cleaning the posts and clamps *completely*, then reconnect them, putting grease on the outside of the clamps. Ensure the clamps are tight after cleaning and before greasing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Everything is clean and the battery is fine, it's new(few months old) and fully charged. Just had it tested at AutoZone.

Comment: Notice, I didn't say the battery is bad. I said the battery connection is not good. Your car is exhibiting classic symptoms of this (from your description). It can look clean without making the connection. Clean them so they are shiney, then reconnect tightly.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What kind of grease do you suggest?

Comment: Like bearing grease. I wouldn't do it until you are sure this has fixed your issue, though. Cleaning it off becomes a chore in between trying to make things work. Check both ends of your cables, too. Could be a bad ground or a bad connection to the starter.

Comment: Especially follow Paulster2's check of both ends of the cable. I had a bad chassis or motor ground at the non-battery end that was intermittent and total grief at the time! Paulster2, put your answer in the form of an answer, as it is a valid contribution.

Comment: When it doesn't start, does it crank at all, or slowly?  The next time it happens, get somebody to wiggle the battery terminals/wires while attempting to start.  Could be a cracked joint between a battery terminal and the cell runners internally.  But start with a voltage drop test on both cables - they will need to be under load.

Comment: @SteveRacer Sometimes it makes a single clicking sound and that's it. In the past it's behaved as if there is no battery at all, I didn't have the power to turn the key, pop the trunk, anything.

Comment: That's probably a thermal effect - the resistance goes up as the temperature increases... and the temperature increases due to the resistance, beleive it or not.  Happens a lot with severely corroded battery cables.  They may *look* fine externally, but if you cut it open the strands will be full of green powder - oxidized copper.